Why can tcp_checksum_complete_user function correctly calculate the TCP checksum after GRO?
for example, kernel 3.10.

When the skb can be passed to the upper layer, it will call tcp4_gro_complete
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v3.10/net/ipv4/tcp_ipv4.c#L2845
th->check only refers to TCP pseudo header checksum?
ip_summed set to CHECKSUM_PARTIAL

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v3.10/net/ipv4/tcp_ipv4.c#L1989
skb->csum = csum_tcpudp_nofold(iph->saddr, iph->daddr,
skb->len, IPPROTO_TCP, 0);
it refers to TCP pseudo header checksum.

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v3.10/net/ipv4/tcp_input.c#L5199
th->check is not the checksum of TCP packets (including data packets).
so why can tcp_checksum_complete_user function correctly calculate the TCP checksum after GRO?


